# sql error using and 3 times

Tags: mysql, sql

I think i might be missing a " or a ' some were from my sql

```
 $result = mysql_query("UPDATE user_pokemon SET level=level+5 WHERE belongsto = '{$_SESSION['username']}' AND slot=1
  AND pokemon = '".$battle_get['pokemon']."'")
```

The third and is the bit which is the problem

```
AND pokemon = '".$battle_get['pokemon']."'")
```

That bit

Comment: I'd recommend being consistent with your variable interpolation style:
    `$result = mysql_query("UPDATE user_pokemon SET level=level+5 WHERE belongsto = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND slot=1 AND pokemon = '".$battle_get['pokemon']."'");`

Comment: Thanks that did the trick maybe make it a answer so i can give you thumbs up ?

Comment: Okay, glad it helped. I added my answer with a little bit of explanation.

Comment: You are missing a lot more than that. For instance proper parametrization with sql-safe-datatypes. And readable code.

Comment: As an aside: are you ensuring your strings are protected from [SQL-injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection)?

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is when interpolating embedded variables, textual subscripts will create a problem if they are qouted.

Try:

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE user_pokemon SET level=level+5 WHERE belongsto = '".$_SESSION['username']."' AND slot=1 AND pokemon = '".$battle_get['pokemon']."'");
```

or

```
$result = mysql_query("UPDATE user_pokemon SET level=level+5 WHERE belongsto = '{$_SESSION[username]}' AND slot=1 AND pokemon = '{$battle_get[pokemon]}'");
```